# New pages aren't being published to the right library (SharePoint 2010)

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, document-library

I created a new pages library, "News Pages", on one of my subsites.

Beforehand, I created some custom site columns, added those to a site content type, and then created a new page layout using those site columns. This page layout is used by default when a new page is created.

But when I create a new page, fill out the fields and publish, it's appearing in the subsite's default "Pages" library, NOT my "News Pages" library.

How would I go about changing my setup so that any new pages are published to "News Pages" library instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SharePoint Publishing Infrastructure is built to handle only one Pages library per web site. This means that you will run into problems trying to add an extra library (believe me, I've tried ;))

The only way to have multiple pages libraries is to create a sub site and use it's pages library.

Comment: That's what I feared. In any case, I appreciate the insight.